# issue with javafx threads

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, javafx

I am doing a javafx application and trying to work with threads. I did some research about similar questions on s.o but none of them answers exactly what I'm asking.

This is my first time working with threads in java fx.

This code downloads 2 images from internet and displays them into an ImageView, also returns some text and put it into a textArea. This piece of code executed with no threads would take about 15 seconds of total GUI freeze.

```
    Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Task <Void> createTask() {
            return new Task<Void>() {           
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception { 

                    //Background work with long tasks

           return null;
            }

    };
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {   
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {

                                //Update GUI (short task)
                    });
                    return null;
                } 
            };
        }
    };
    service.start();
```

But when I execute this code WITH the concurrency thread, the GUI does not get frozen anymore  (at least) but the code doesn't execute well (the images are not downloaded and therefore the GUI is not updated). What can I do in those cases?

Comment: Have you checked to see if you are getting an exception in the call(...) method?

Comment: Yes , no exceptions. I'm really sure there's something wrong with the concurrency implementation.